# Can I change the type of my float number?

Tags: python, sympy

I have a complex number `5.86992761-5.08757736e-17j`, after taking its real part using `sympy`, it becomes `5.86992761171210`, with the type `<class 'sympy.core.numbers.Float'>`. I'm wondering is there a way I can change the type to `<class 'float'>`?

Comment: `float(5.86992761171210)`

Comment: @Pedro Lobito Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

use the `float()` function will turn it into <class 'float'>